# How to Auto-mount Azure Storage Account to Linux VM

Tags: azure, mount, azure-storage-account, azure-vm

I am trying to mount an Azure storage account to a VM by following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-quick-create-use-linux

Seems it works, but I need to re-mount after VM reboot.

Can I update /etc/fstab so it will auto-mount after VM reboot?

Currently I specify the Azure file storage account size when creating it (100GB in the example). Can I mount to a Azure file storage account without specifying size, so it can auto-scale and pay as it goes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mount a NFS file share permanently even after the vm reboot then you need to update the fstab as explained in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux?tabs=smb311#automatically-mount-file-shares)

> Can I mount to a Azure file storage account without specifying size,
> so it can auto-scale and pay as it goes?

No you cannot.[NFS file shares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-how-to-mount-nfs-shares) are supported for premium storage accounts only. 100GB is the minimum storage/quota allocated when you create a NFS file share and you can expand up to 102400GB by using `change size and performance` option as shown in below image

[image]

Comment: Thanks VenkateshDodda for your response.

However the document is for auto-mounting SMB Azure file share on Linux, and I am looking for auto-mounting NFS file share to Linux. 


Can I auto-mount NFS file share to Linux after reboot?

What're main differences between NFS file and SMB file? Which one should I use if I want to replace the attached disk in VM?

Thanks a lot.